# Maven clean ignore single file

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a Maven project that is an aggregation of a number of sub-projects.  This project uses the maven javadoc plugin to aggregate all sub-project javadocs into a single directory in the `target/` folder.  I have an additional file in the `target/` folder that I would like to remain in with the javadoc pages.  However, every time I run a `clean`, this file would be deleted.  I was wondering if there was a way to delete the whole target directory and leave only a single file.  My plugin is currently configured like so:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <execution>
      <executions>
        <id>default-clean</id>
        <configuration>
          <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
            <filesets>
              <fileset>
                <directory>target</directory>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>path/to/myFile.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
              <fileset>
           </filesets>
         </configuration>
       <phase>initialize</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>clean</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801439/maven-clean-plugin-exclude-cvsignore), but the solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Where is this supplemental file comming from ? Generated or what?

Comment: the supplemental file is static and lives in the target/path/to/myFile.xml directory.  It supplements some of the html generated, so I just keep it with the HTML rather than having to copy it.  If this project were not an aggregation, I could just put it in a src folder and let it copy over, but since it' an aggregation I thought /target would be the only place I could put it.

Comment: Possible hack: What if you mark the file read-only or change the owner to `root`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that static file in a resources folder and let the `maven-resources-plugin` copy it to the specific target folder.

Comment: That's what I would up doing, although I think it's kind of odd that the clean plugin doesn't have a simple way to exclude a file!

Comment: @Joshc1107 But if you want to clean up, do you want to leave dirt behind?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need and after playing a while with the plugin I found a working solution for avoiding to delete specific files inside the target folder.

Let's suppose that you don't want to delete the file `do_not_delete` in the `target` folder, this configuration works for me:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>target</directory>
                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                <useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>do_not_delete</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, it is possible to explicitly exclude or include files form your project. Are you positive about the exclude path you provided?

```
<filesets>
  <fileset>
    <directory>src/main/generated</directory>
    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
    <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
    <includes>
      <include>*.java</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>MyPathRelativeToDirectoryTag/myFile.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </fileset>
</filesets>
```